# How do you create a .XNB Font file for use with CocosSharp?

Tags: xna, monogame, fonts

I know the .XNB file format is an XNA thing and that [CocosSharp](https://github.com/mono/CocosSharp) inherits this from its MonoGame roots. However there doesn't seem to be any information on how to create your own .XNB fonts to use with CocosSharp. I've tried searching but can find any information.

Could someone explain it here or point me to a tutorial on how to create .XNB font file for use with CocosSharp?

A site to download already compiled .XNB Fonts would also be acceptable.

Update: Another thing that makes this tricky is that I guess XNA Game Studio could be used, but it's not compatible with Windows 8.1; which is what I currently use for my dev machine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Monogame cannot (yet) generate XNB files so you will need to use the original content builder from XNA 4.0 https://github.com/xupefei/XNA-4.0-Content-Compiler.